# Unable to create index on MongoDB local using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create custom index on MongoDB but it is not creating when I check on mongodb-compass and via command line.

This is Mongoose model

```
import Mongoose from "mongoose";
// import encrypt from "mongoose-encryption";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from "path";

const __dirname = path.resolve();

dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" });

const signupSchema = new Mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: [true, "name required"] },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "email required"],
      unique: true,
      index: true,
    },
    phoneNumber: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "phone number required"],
      unique: true,
      index: true,
    },
    currentLocation: {
      type: String,
      required: [false, "current location required"],
    },
    password: { type: String, required: [true, "password requred"] },

    createdDate:{
      type:Date,
      default:Date.now
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    timeseries: true,
  }
);

// const secretkey = process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY;

// signupSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secretkey });

signupSchema.index({email:1,type:1})

const SignUpModel = Mongoose.model("SignUp", signupSchema);
export default SignUpModel;
```

My index.js

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/naukridb',{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
 
})
mongoose.pluralize(null)
```

Compass Image to see index not created even when defined in model:

[image]

This is my command line to check:

[image]

No index is created on email and phone number, and unique instance is also not working.

Tried and tested:

[Mongoose create multiple indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024587/mongoose-create-multiple-indexes)
[Mongoose not creating index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786839/mongoose-not-creating-index)
[Mongoose Not Creating Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452865/mongoose-not-creating-indexes)
[Mongoose does not create text index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525871/mongoose-does-not-create-text-index)
[mongoose index don't create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65591787/mongoose-index-dont-create)
[Mongoose Secondary Index is not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811836/mongoose-secondary-index-is-not-created)

But no solution is working. My MongoDB version is 5.0.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by setting `timeseries : true` on the schema. I'm not sure if this is a Mongoose issue, a MongoDB issue, or intended behaviour.

You can ensure your secondary indexes get created by using `ensureIndexes`:

```
const SignUpModel = Mongoose.model("SignUp", signupSchema);
await SignUpModel.ensureIndexes();
```

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error MongooseError: Operation `SignUp.createIndex()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Comment: TimeSeries was the problem actually, after removing it is working